# Android - PreferenceActivity - Change color of Summary text of CheckBoxPreference

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am trying to change the summary text color of the CheckBoxPreference.  I have changed the text color of the title by specifying a theme but it doesn't seem to be registering with the summary portion.  Here is my theme.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="settings_theme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/light_gray</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And I am calling this in the onCreate method of my settings activity:

```
setTheme(R.style.settings_theme);
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Add this to the style.xml in your theme:

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/light_gray</item>
```

Comment: best and the most solution i have seen